# Python fill a dict with list of values

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

I am looking for a simple way to put all elements of a given array as values in a dictionary.

At the moment it looks like this:

```
    for i, e in enumerate(list):
        passiv_dict = {
            "key1": [list[i][0]],
            "key2": [list[i][1]],
        }
```

Comment: Did you mean for each value in the `dict` to a be `list`?

Answer (score 4):

using list comprehensions(python 2.7 as example)

```
l = range(3)
d = {i:e for i,e in enumerate(l)}
```

Answer (score 2):

At the moment you are creating a new dictionary for each element. You need to create the dict then add to it.

Something like

```
passive_dict = {}
for i, e in enumerate(list):
    passive_dict[i] = e
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you are wanting something like this,

```
my_dict = dict(('key{}'.format(index), val) for index, val in enumerate(range(3)))
```

printing `my_dict` will give you a dictionary like this,

```
{'key0': 0, 'key1': 1, 'key2': 2}
```

here, you need to pass your list instead of `range(3)`

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite clear to know what you are looking for from your description. however, given your sample code, I assume your base list is something like that:

```
l = [['apple', 'red'],['pear','green'],['lemon','yellow']]
```

A simple call to the `dict` constructor will lead to:

```
>>> dict(l)
{'lemon': 'yellow', 'pear': 'green', 'apple': 'red'}
```

To match (?) your expected output format we might try:

```
>>> {key:item for key, item in enumerate(l)}
{0: ['apple', 'red'], 1: ['pear', 'green'], 2: ['lemon', 'yellow']}
```

Or this slight variation:

```
>>> {"key{}".format(key):item for key, item in enumerate(l)}
{'key2': ['lemon', 'yellow'], 'key1': ['pear', 'green'], 'key0': ['apple', 'red']}
```

But, maybe you need this (sub-optimal) representation instead:

```
>>> [{idx:val for idx,val in enumerate(item)} for item in l]
[{0: 'apple', 1: 'red'}, {0: 'pear', 1: 'green'}, {0: 'lemon', 1: 'yellow'}]
```

Or:

```
>>> [{"key{}".format(idx):val for idx,val in enumerate(item)} for item in l]
[{'key1': 'red', 'key0': 'apple'}, {'key1': 'green', 'key0': 'pear'}, {'key1': 'yellow', 'key0': 'lemon'}]
```

(don't pay too much attention to the keys order, as dictionaries are *not* ordered).

---

Finally, if you need *arbitrary* labels, use this technique:

```
>>> labels={0: 'fruit',1: 'color'}
>>> [{labels[idx]:val for idx,val in enumerate(item)} for item in l]
[{'color': 'red', 'fruit': 'apple'}, {'color': 'green', 'fruit': 'pear'}, {'color': 'yellow', 'fruit': 'lemon'}]
```

With all those variation, you have the basic building blocks to do almost whatever you want. For a formal introduction to *dictionary comprehensions*, take a look at [PEP-274](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary can be constructed from a sequence of tuples, which is what `enumerate` produces:

```
l = range(3)
d = dict(enumerate(l))
```